# cloud foundry installation error

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

While installing my app on **"cloud foundry"**, I am getting an `error: null`
when I execute these commands:

1. grails prod cf-info
2. grails prod cf-push

But returns `error: NULL`

What do I do ***to install the app to cloud foundry***?

Comment: help plzzzzzzzz,...............

Comment: Have you tried working on a known good app and pushing to Cloud Foundry? For example, can you follow this tutorial and push the Grails Petclinic app? http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/12/one-step-deployment-with-grails-and-cloud-foundry/

Comment: Also, have you tried with version 1.2.2 of the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Glenn's comment, "Have you tried working on a known good app and pushing to Cloud Foundry? For example, can you follow this tutorial and push the Grails Petclinic app?": Yesterday I tried the Petclinic app with grails 2.0.4 in conjunction with the Cloud Foundry plug-in 1.2.2, and was successful.